# iPhone web application : the virtual keyboard opens unexpectedly

Tags: ios, keyboard, web, virtual-keyboard

I am having a very weird issue on an iPhone and I would like to have suggestions on the best way to troubleshoot.  My web application works fine for a moment then suddenly all text fields and buttons will have no effect, but only to open the virtual keyboard.

For example, a "delete" button which used to display a "yes/Cancel" modal will only make the keyboard open, the modal won't show up... When I reload the page, everything is working as expected again.

I am testing with an iPhone 6 and Chrome.

Did someone already encountered an issue like that?

I have absolutely no idea how to track down this behaviour and all suggestions are welcomed, What do you suggest I should look in priority?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this weird, weird behaviour...  Could it be an issue in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was coming from a bug in a version of Chrome I was using at that moment (I have no idea which one, since my phone has regular automatic updates).

I strongly advise to have always at lease two different platforms when testing websites!